# Launching Form from Textbox blocks event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I ran into this curious problem in WPF.
An application to run on Touchscreen needs a Keypad for data entry.
I am launching this keypad from a mainform. This is done by clicking or tapping a textbox on the mainform.
After tapping the keypad is launched, but consequently the first click with a finger on the touchscreen is ingnored i.e the click event does not fire.
If the first click is done with a mouse, dan the event is fired

Code like here:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  Point positie = new Point();
  positie.Y = this.Top + this.Height;
  positie.X = (this.Width / 20) * 2;
  Mouse.Synchronize();

  KeyboardWindow kb = new KeyboardWindow(positie, (TextBox)sender);
  kb.ShowDialog();
  kb = null;
}
```

If I lauch the same Keypad from an button on the mainform, than it all works like is is intended:
The first click event on the keypad is fired if touched with finger or clicked with a mouse.

Code:

```
private void btnKb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Point positie = new Point();
  positie.Y = this.Top + this.Height;
  positie.X = (this.Width / 20) * 2;
  KeyboardWindow kb = new KeyboardWindow(positie, (TextBox)txtTest);
  kb.ShowDialog();
  kb = null;
}
```

Now what could be causing the missing of the first click.

Hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because TextBox handles the MouseDown to focus itself if it's not focused. So the first time someone clicks it get's focused and your event doesn't get called.

Easiest fix subscribe for GotFocus as well.

EDIT

Another easy way is to subscribe for handled events like this:

```
this.MyTextBox.AddHandler( UIElement.PreviewMouseDownEvent, MyTextBox_PreviewMouseDown, true );
```

Comment: You were right about the Focus I guess. Nevertheless your remarks did not lead to fixing the problem. I ended up using Stylus and Mouse in my Xaml. Stylus did not have this focus behaviour